# Calling an external css file is not having the same result when the same css is used as internal css

Tags: html, css

If I take css script from this example [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar_click) and I put it into 2 external css file (`font.css` and `menu.css`) and then I called them in html, the arrow from Dropdown menu disappear.

The content from `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css` is in `font.css` and the entire content of tag `<style>` is in `menu.css`.

I can't include web link because I don't have access to internet where I want to create this.

The code ended like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font.css" >
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu.css" >
</head>
<body>
  <!–– Rest of the code...-->
</body>

 </html>
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. The css files you linked doesn't load here either, and if we can't see it, we can't fix it.

Comment: Did the css files load ? as in did you get a 200 status over network call ?

Comment: did you add the jquery? `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">` I mean this

Comment: Hi @Bob, the example you linked to on W3Schools uses [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/) as you can see in Dev Tools (`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">` is included in the `<head>`). Make sure to add it if you want it to work ;)

Comment: @ I made a file called `font.css` with the script from `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css` I forgot to mention that I don't have access to internet.

Comment: @BOB you have to put the link in the head of your html/php file

Comment: @xmastertje Where I want to implement this I don't have access to internet.

Comment: Well then download the FontAwesome CSS and font files  locally, and embed them from there.

Comment: @04FS As you see in the html code I made that

Comment: @BOB download the library locally and include it from there

Comment: @BOB i edited my answer. This has to work

Comment: You need to download more than just the CSS file, you need the font files it refers to inside as well.

Answer (score 1):

its not enough to copy content of https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css to your css file! since there is some linked fonts and images that directed by "**Relational Path**"
in this case you have to use External CSS URL replaceing with your local css file
means;
replace

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font.css" >
```

with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

or if you want to use **offline** , you have to download **FontAwesome toolkit** from 
https://fontawesome.com/download
and use it in your source code
there is sample files in downloaded archive file...

Comment: What file from archive do I need to include in my code?

Comment: for using all features of this toolkit you have to copy all extracted folders beside your index.html or etc ... also you can place them inside a folder
but the main needed folders are css,webfonts
here is sample scenario;
you have your own index.html file and placed css,webfonts beside it now you have to include following code inside your <head> tag:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.css">`